# Perforce: How to list changed files like P4V "Diff Against" shows?

Tags: perforce

I am very new to Perforce. I submitted changed files to Perforce, but accidentally used "Submit All Files".

Using P4V's "Diff Against" menu item, I can see and step through just the changed/added files in the "Folder Diff" UI by specifying my change list number and the change list number that created the branch I submitted to.

How can I just get a simple list of the file names to add to the commit log? I've been asked to do this so reviewers know which files they need to look at. (There are around 100, too many to do manually.) Just the files added or with content differences, not the unmodified ones accidentally included in the change list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
p4 diff2 -q -Od //...@CHANGE-1 //...@CHANGE
```

That'll do a content-based diff of the state of the entire repository before and after your changelist CHANGE, with only differing files being listed.

Comment: I don't have the -Od option, but I got it to work with a little manual cleanup. Thanks for taking the time to answer!!